# How do I access pipenv after a successful installation?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I just installed pipenv, yet pipenv isn’t available in my shell post-installation. I'm struggling to follow the instructions from [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/): [macOS Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCujn.png)

My user base binary directory is: `/Users/DoubleA/Library/Python/3.6`

When I enter `nano ~/.bash_profile`, here's what's entered into my profile: [Bash Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIDr1.png)

Can someone help me discover where I've gone wrong, so that I can continue setting up my pip environment per Hitchhiker's instructions?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please copy the relevant code into the question.

Comment: You should probably add the bin dir to the front of your path instead of the end. And you also need to source your .bash_profile after you change it.

Comment: ^ This means typing `source ~/.bash_profile` into your terminal